# PDF of Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, gaussian-integral

Can you please explain me why we have two different PDFs for Rayleigh distribution as follows,

1) $(x/\sigma^2 )         \times  e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$

and

2) $(2x/\sigma^2)       \times  e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}$

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent to each other, but just different parametrizations. You try to substitute $\sigma^2$ by $s^2/2$ into the first parametrization, then you will get the second form.